# How to free port in Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, port

I want to use port no localhost:3000 for rails and that is already taken other process How can i free this port no ?

I have run this command

```
ruby abc/script/server
```

and facing this error

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/utils.rb:85:in `initialize': Address already in use - bind(2) (Errno::EADDRINUSE)
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/utils.rb:85:in `new'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/utils.rb:85:in `block in create_listeners'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/utils.rb:82:in `each'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/utils.rb:82:in `create_listeners'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:82:in `listen'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:70:in `initialize'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:45:in `initialize'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/handler/webrick.rb:10:in `new'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/handler/webrick.rb:10:in `run'
from /var/www/abc/vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/server.rb:111:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from abc/script/server:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What is `ps -e | grep ruby` result?

Answer (score 3):

`netstat -tulpn | grep 3000`  - will give you the PID of the process

e.g :

```
tcp    0   0 0.0.0.0:3000    0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN      5726/ruby1.9.1
```

Here `5726` is the PID, kill it using `kill -9 5726`

Answer (score 2):

try something like this:

```
lsof -wni tcp:3000
```

will show like this:

```
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ruby    3824 rony    9r  IPv4  50665      0t0  TCP *:3001 (LISTEN)
```

Then kill this with this `PID`:

```
kill -9 3824
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could also start rails server on a different port

```
rails server -p 4000
```